# Azure Media Services Streaming Allowed IP Addresses not working

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-media-player

I was able to list IP addresses and only allow them to play videos previously. For some reason, this no longer working now.

The IPs that I am using is of a VPN. Could that be an issue? If I list a non-VPN IP it does seem to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

With a VPN you will typically end up with a different public IP address. I would recommend checking the public IP that would be seen on the endpoint for your VPN and also ensure that this doesn't dynamically change. Beyond ensuring you have specified the correct IP address and that it doesn't change there isn't anything unique about using a VPN that would cause IP's in your allow list to not work.